# Need an example to create a Component In cq5 to render the XML structure of the siteMap

Tags: aem, sitemap

Is there any example or tutorial to create a component , which will render XML of a sitemap.

Comment: Do you mean the sitemap.xml used by indexing bots? You can simply create a SlingServlet (extensions="xml") or JSP (*.xml.jsp) to render such an XML.

Comment: Maybe ACS Commons Sitemap will work https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/simple-sitemap.html